# How to access full Adobe Acrobat AcroExch COM API from Internet Explorer embedded object?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, ui-automation, acrobat

I have the following situation:

- Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 SP1 32-bit
- Adobe Acrobat Professional version 10
- A webpage with code like this:

`<object data="foo.pdf" src="foo.pdf">`

Given that:

- The default PDF reader on the system is Adobe Acrobat
- Adobe Reader's browser plugin is suppressed in favor of Acrobat's plugin
- Acrobat.exe is running when the plugin loads
- I'm using Internet Explorer's COM automation (from Ruby, but that doesn't really matter) to obtain a reference to the `object`'s `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` object

With this `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` object, I need to manipulate form fields, read text, and do other stuff that is perfectly reasonable to do with the `AcroExch.PDDoc` API, and then click a button on the webpage (using IE automation) to serialize the form fields to XML and save them to the webserver.

I need to test this "end to end" from a user perspective due to business requirements, so I can't just stuff values in the XML and see if the server takes them.

Is there any way to access the `AcroExch.PDDoc` APIs of the opened PDF document from the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` reference, **without** saving the PDF to a file on disk and opening it in using `AcroExch.App`?

The problem is that if I save it to disk and re-open it in Acrobat, that file cannot be used to save and submit the form field data to the web server, as far as I know. (*Or can it*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to access the AcroExch.PDDoc APIs of the opened PDF
>   document from the AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF reference, without saving the
>   PDF to a file on disk and opening it in using AcroExch.App?

I don't think you can do this with `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF`. Check ["Developing for Adobe® Reader®"](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf), page 25 ("OLE automation"):

> On Windows, **the only** OLE automation supported for Adobe Reader is the
>   PDF browser controls interface, which enables you to treat a PDF
>   document as an ActiveX document within an external application. This
>   makes it possible to **load a file, move to various pages within the
>   file, highlight a text selection, and specify various print and
>   display options**, as shown below.

Further, there's a detailed list of the supported APIs, and you can also confirm that with [OleView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It *might* be possible to develop an Adobe Acrobat plugin, but:

> Any plug-ins written for Adobe Reader must be Reader-enabled, which
>   means that you will need to obtain permission and licensing from Adobe
>   Systems.

Comment: This is most puzzling, since Adobe **Reader** is not in the picture at all. Reader does not activate when opening an embedded PDF on this system; **Acrobat** does. `Acrobat.exe` runs when the PDF is displayed in a browser. Are you saying that when Acrobat is embedded in a browser window, it's only as capable as Reader?

Comment: @allquixotic, I'm saying that the set of APIs available on the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` ActiveX control  is the same, regardless of whether you have just Reader or full Acrobat installed on a particular PC. I believe the reason behind this is that this ActiveX was initially designed as IE plugin, and the set of APIs was deliberately limited to [these](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.167.html&accessible=true).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a search, an I'd found [this VBScript example](http://www.justskins.com/forums/programmatically-signing-a-pdf-13908.html):

```
Set acrobatApplication = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set gPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

If gPDDoc.Open("c:\adobe.pdf") Then
Set jso = gPDDoc.GetJSObject
Set oAdd = jso.addField("FirmaField1", "signature", 0, Array(20, 100,
100, 20))
Set oSign = jso.getField("FirmaField1")
Set ppklite = jso.security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKLite", True)

ppklite.login "1111", "c:\certificate_file.pfx"
oSign.signatureSign ppklite
ppklite.logout
end if
```

It is clear that he use there the **AcroExch.PDDoc**. Maybe you can run it from the browser, or the Javascript equivalent.